# java 16 on raspberry pi java: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, minecraft, raspberry-pi4

When I'm trying to install java 16 on my raspberry pi for a 1.17 minecraft server, I get the following error.

java: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

If somebody has the same error or knows how to fix it, pls let me know.

I'm running rasbian 64 bit

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Debian packages for libz.so.1](https://packages.debian.org/search?mode=path&suite=jessie&section=all&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=libz.so.1) you need to run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install zlib1g
```